# Honoring @SuppressWarnings with the sonar checkstyle plugin

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

Is there any possibility to configure SonarQube 5.1 with Checkstyle plugin to honor the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation. I do not want to turn off 'Avoid use of deprecated methods' rule, I just want to SonarQube honor the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

I have a Java code in which I need to use deprecated `createValidator()` method as following:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public javax.xml.bind.Validator createValidator() throws JAXBException {
    return contextDelegate.createValidator();
}
```

Java compiler does not warning when compiling code, but unfortunately SonarQube with CheckStyle plugin rise a issue:

```
squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod
Avoid use of deprecated methods
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squid is a different kind of beast. As suggested in the [SonarQube docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ#JavaFAQ-SuppressWarnings), you'll have to use a slightly different syntax, e.g.:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod")
```

The string `squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod` is the SonarQube *rule key*.

Unfortunately, this means adding *two* annotations to effectively suppress the deprecation warning. But afaik, it's the only way short of disabling the rule.

Comment: why two, we can use both the annotations in the single annotation use?

Comment: Sure, you can `@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod"})`, but that's syntactic sugar ;-) @KumarAnkit

Answer (score 1):

Squid is a name or number of Sonar Rule, no relationship to checkstyle, all checkstyle rules are described at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html