# squid:S3415 broken?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a line of code in a unit test that says

```
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("mystringconstant", MyObject.MYCONSTANT);
```

Despite of the parameter description of `assertEquals(expected,actual)` SQ keeps telling me that

```
squid:S3415 Swap these 2 arguments so they are in the correct order: expected value, actual value.
```

is violated. IMHO this should be no issue unless I'm missing something.

I use SQ 6.5 and SonarJava 4.15.0.12310.

Can someone confitm this behaviour?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what Sonarqube is doing is checking that the second arg is "more concrete" (for lack of a better term) than the first, e.g. constant vs. variable, local variable vs. function return, etc. In this case, it considers a static final string and an interred string as equal, meaning no matter the order, it flags them. You can trick it by assigning the constant to a variable and then doing the assertion against the variable: 

String x = Const.MY_CONST; 
assertEquals("test", x);

But I agree there should be some way of avoiding this flag at all.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, you can silence this via Sonarqube's warning suppression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379959/honoring-suppresswarnings-with-the-sonar-checkstyle-plugin which seems reasonable. It would be nice to have it not occur in the first place, but given that there's an easy enough workaround, I'm not sure it's high priority.